# Converting forEach to map

Tags: javascript, html, css, coding-style, array.prototype.map

**Some people said that forEach inside this function is not good and that i should use maps. So, im wodering how do i use maps for this**

Some people said that forEach inside this function is not good and that i should use maps. So, im wodering how do i use maps for this:
*I also want this to be a reusable function so i could just call it anywhere*

**How do i make this code much cleaner. Without Jquery**

JS:

```
const about = document.getElementById('about');
const numbers = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
const svgEl = document.querySelectorAll('svg circle');
const counters = Array(numbers.length);
const intervals = Array(counters.length);
counters.fill(0);

function moveprogressbar() { numbers.forEach((number, index) => {
    intervals[index] = setInterval(() => {
        if(counters[index] === parseInt(number.dataset.num)){
            clearInterval(counters[index]);
        } else{
            counters[index] += 1;
            number.textContent = counters[index] + "%";
            svgEl[index].style.strokeDashoffset = Math.floor(472 - 440 * parseFloat(number.dataset.num / 100));
        }
    }, 20);
 });
}
```

Comment: What is `numbers`, `counters` and `intervals`? How are you going to resuse it?

Comment: @adiga ``` const numbers = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
const svgEl = document.querySelectorAll('svg circle');
const counters = Array(numbers.length);
const intervals = Array(counters.length);``` i defined using const

Comment: Something like this: `const intervals = Array.from(numbers, (number, index) => setInterval(...))`

Comment: well. i just want to run this code inside an intersectionObserver. How?

Comment: What difference doe that make? The code I've suggested is just a replacement of what you already have inside `moveprogressbar`

Comment: it has no errors now. but still didnt work

Answer (score 0):

just change forEach with map keyword to use map and
Unlike forEach map will return you a new array but if you just want to iterate i think forEach is good choice over map

```
const about = document.getElementById('about');
const numbers = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
const svgEl = document.querySelectorAll('svg circle');
const counters = Array(numbers.length); 
const intervals = Array(counters.length);
counters.fill(0);
let numberArray =[]
numberberArray.push[numbers]
function moveprogressbar() { numberArray.map((number, index) => {
intervals[index] = setInterval(() => {
    if(counters[index] === parseInt(number.dataset.num)){
        clearInterval(counters[index]);
    } else{
        counters[index] += 1;
        number.textContent = counters[index] + "%";
        svgEl[index].style.strokeDashoffset = Math.floor(472 - 440  
* parseFloat(number.dataset.num / 100));
    }
   }, 20);
 });
}
```

Comment: the console says numbers.Map is not a function

Comment: Map is an array method so it will work only with arrays, Are numbers array?

Comment: i defined array as ```const numbers = document.querySelectorAll('.number');```

Comment: whats the log when you console log the numbers , is it like this [1,2,3,4..]  or something else and is it working before whn using forEach

Comment: it says nodelist. it has 0,1,2,3. and yes it is working with forEach

Comment: its not an array so you need to convert it to Array , because map only works with array,and did you write 'map' or 'Map" , map has to be in lowercase

Comment: i wrote map too. how do i convert it to an array?

Comment: also i edit my question you may want to take a look

Comment: You can try pushing each element into an empty array first then when you done, you can use map

Comment: try this maybe it work

Comment: it says numberArray is not defined

Comment: try defining numberArray at top of the code , it not gonna do anything but try it maybe it works and make sure to spell everything right

Comment: also i just want to call this inside an IntersectionObserver: ```
const animatecarousel = new IntersectionObserver(function (entries, animatecarousel) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if(!entry.isIntersecting) {
   // moveprogressbar();
    }
  });
}, startanimation);
animatecarousel.observe(test);```

Comment: https://medium.com/@ryanfinni/the-intersection-observer-api-practical-examples-7844dfa429e9, try this article maybe it helps

Answer (score -1):

It's just simple use map keyword instead of forEach

```
function moveprogressbar() { numbers.map((number, index) => {
        intervals[index] = setInterval(() => {
        if(counters[index] === parseInt(number.dataset.num)){
         clearInterval(counters[index]);
         } else{
        counters[index] += 1;
        number.textContent = counters[index] + "%";
       svgEl[index].style.strokeDashoffset = Math.floor(472 - 440 * parseFloat(number.dataset.num / 100));
               }
           }, 20);
        });
       }
```

Comment: the console says numbers.Map is not a function

Comment: It's `map` not `Map`. Also, there is no point in converting `forEach` to `map` if you are not using the array returned by the `map`

Comment: you are right @adiga it's just a typo error.

Comment: @adiga and how do i do that?

Comment: and yes i did map too